# PowerShell Import-CSV format datetime: Data is be represented as 00:00:0 in the file output when the file has 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000

Tags: powershell

I have tried formatting the dates and have not had any luck.
Sample data:

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00.000,2021-01-24 00:00:00.000,2021-01-01 00:00:00.000,15,17,15,17,22,402219.89,402219.89,457621.22,457621.22,597385.79,10,1855180.96,169651.66,1235781.38,6.30,155963.88,155963.88,188556.81,188556.81,-214.63,-155.97
```

```
$data = import-csv $impcsv -header 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'MonthStart','ytdDays', 'pyDays', 
 'MTDDays','PMTDDays','PFullMTDDays','ytd', 'mtd', 'pytd', 'pmtd', 'pfullmtd', 'whs', 'inventory', 
 'onorderinventory', 'onpo', 'yearpct', 'ytd_gp', 'mtd_gp', 'pytd_gp', 'pmtdd_gp', 'daily', 
 'daily_gp'  


 $count = 1 

 foreach($i in $data){ 

 [string]$StartDate = $I.StartDate 
 [string]$EndDate = $I.EndDate 
 [string]$MonthStart = $i.MonthStart
 [single]$ytdDays = $i.ytdDays
 [single]$pyDays = $i.pyDays
 [single]$MTDDays = $i.MTDDays
 [single]$PMTDDays = $i.PMTDDays
 [single]$PFullMTDDays = $i.PFullMTDDays
 [single]$ytd = $i.ytd
 [single]$MTD = $i.MTD
 [single]$pytd = $i.pytd 
 [single]$pmtd = $i.pytd 
 [single]$pfullmtd = $i.pfullmtd 
 [string]$whs = $i.whs 
 [single]$inventory = $i.inventory 
 [single]$onorderinventory = $i.onorderinventory 
 [single]$onpo = $i.onpo 
 [single]$yearpct = $i.yearpct 
 [single]$ytd_gp = $i.ytd_gp 
 [single]$mtd_gp = $i.mtd_gp 
 [single]$pytd_gp = $i.pytd_gp 
 [single]$pmtdd_gp = $i.pmtdd_gp 
 [single]$daily= $i.daily 
 [single]$daily_gp = $i.daily_gp 


  $query = "INSERT INTO $table (StartDate, EndDate, MonthStart, ytdDays, pyDays, 
                          MTDDays,PMTDDays,PFullMTDDays, ytd, mtd, pytd, pmtd, pfullmtd, whs, 
                          inventory,onorderinventory, onpo, yearpct, ytd_gp, mtd_gp, pytd_gp, 
                          pmtdd_gp, daily, daily_gp) 
         VALUES ('$StartDate', '$EndDate', '$MonthStart', '$ytdDays', '$pyDays', 
                 '$MTDDays','$PMTDDays','$PFullMTDDays','$ytd', '$mtd', '$pytd', '$pmtd', 
                 '$pfullmtd', '$whs', '$inventory', '$onorderinventory', '$onpo', 
                 '$yearpct','$ytd_gp','$mtd_gp', '$pytd_gp','$pmtdd_gp', '$daily', '$daily_gp')" 

  invoke-sqlcmd -Database $databaseName -ServerInstance $ServerName -Username $username -Password 
  $password  -Query $query
                    
  write-host $startDate 
  write-host "Processing row ..........$count" -foregroundcolor green 

  $count  = $count + 1 

  }
```

Comment: How are you trying to format the DateTime values? Can you please share the code snippet for the same?

Comment: I tried using ParseExact and -f format. Why does the object in the read from the import-CSV  translate  2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 as 00:00:0.  I did not have issues with dates until time was added.

Comment: What is the datatype of the date columns in the SQL table? PowerShell just passes a string in your code, so PowerShell [DateTime] logic is never involved at all.

Comment: I have tried Datetime and varchar.  The issue is in the import-csv. When I write to host from $data csv file date is 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 get translated to 00:00:0.    When inserted to SQL Server when it is varchar it stores 00:00:0 and  when datetime datatype it gets translated 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: I was thinking that the date within the Import-CSV CMD would require some type of reformatting of the Date because once it is in the $DATA variable is is represented as 00:00:0.

Comment: :$data = import-csv $impcsv -header 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'MonthStart','ytdDays', 'pyDays', 'MTDDays','PMTDDays','PFullMTDDays','ytd', 'mtd', 'pytd', 'pmtd', 'pfullmtd', 'whs', 'inventory', 'onorderinventory', 'onpo', 'yearpct', 'ytd_gp', 
    
                     'mtd_gp', 'pytd_gp', 'pmtdd_gp', 'daily', 'daily_gp' |  ForEach-Object {   $_.StartDate=[datetime]::ParseExact($($_.StartDate),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',$null)  ,$_.EndDate=[datetime]::ParseExact($($_.EndDate),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',$null),  $_.MonthStart=[datetime]::ParseExact($($_.MonthStart),'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss',$null)}

Comment: error message: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Users\jim.v\OneDrive - Midland Industries\Midland DW\PowerShell\BRL Load Daily Sales.ps1:15 char:298
+ ... $null),  $_.MonthStart=[datetime]::ParseExact($($_.MonthStart),'yyyy- ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: Try converting it to a string (after parsing) and provide a format specifier to that string. Something like: `$_.StartDate=[datetime]::Parse($_.StartDate).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`.

Comment: At this time I was not able to get this working.  I had the csv file modified to just be a date and not include time.  I will continue to investigate the approached to fix this data. At this time we can close the question.  Tank you everyone who took a look at the issue...